# Laravel 5.5 multi-level menu query order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am trying to get all links in one query ordered by parent_id, level, weight  to avoid recursivity.

I have recursive relations defined in the model and everything works fine but I  would prefer to avoid using them.

```
/**
 * Get parents recursive.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function parentRecursive()
{
    return $this->parent()->with(['parentRecursive']);
}

/**
 * Parent.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Link::class, 'parent_id');
}

/**
 * Get children recursive.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function childrenRecursive()
{
    return $this->children()->with(['childrenRecursive'])->orderBy('weight', 'asc');
}

/**
 * Children.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

The dropdown should look like:

```
-Level 1
    --Level 1.1
    --Level 1.2
        ---Level 1.2.1 
        ---Level 1.2.2 
    --Level 1.3
-Level 2
    --Level 1.1 
-Level 3
    --Level 1.1 
-Level 4
    --Level 1.1 
-Level 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Nested Sets (e.g. https://github.com/etrepat/baum package).

It will allow you to do:

```
$tree = Category::where('name', '=', 'Books')->first()->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();
```

Which returns a collection tree and takes exactly one query.